# Need to bind documents spread between multiple Document Libraries

Tags: document-set

I have a requirement of binding documents stored in 2 document libraries.
Document library1 : stores Masterpiece document
Document library2 : stores supporting documents.

The binding should be such that for every Master piece document in DL1 there are multiple supporting documents in DL2 ( one to many).

How can we bind documents stored between 2 DL ?

Can Document Set bind documents distributed between 2 Document libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Master document library as a Lookup column in Supporting Document Library.. And create a master-child relationship..